# Does Quantized graph uses gemmlowp instead of eigen in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I was disassembling the benchmark app with arm objdump, it has gemmlowp integrated, but I couldnt see `-DUSE_GEMMLOWP` is enabled in Makefile for `TARGET=ANDROID`.

Also does quantized graph when run on cpu, does it use GEMMLOWP

thanks

Comment: Partial answer is when graph is quantized, quantization tool will substitute most of the quantized routines like quantize_conv_op, quantize_instance_norm with gemmlowp implementation. this is evident from tracing back the calls from quantization tool to op substitution.